# Should a docstring go before or after a decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, pep8, docstring

Compare the following.

Example 1: docstring before decorator.

```py
@app.route("/")
"""
summary
"""
def hello() -> str:
    return "Hello World"
```

versus example 2: docstring after decorator:

```py
"""
summary
"""
@app.route("/")
def hello() -> str:
    return "Hello World"
```

Comment: I'd put it after the `def` ...

Comment: Seeing as how Example 1 is a syntax error, I'd go with Example 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Where should the docstring go?

The docstring should go inside the function, the first thing after the function header:

```
@app.route("/")
def hello() -> str:
    """
    summary
    """
    return "Hello World"
```

The specification itself ([PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#id4)) makes it explicit:

> A docstring is a string literal that occurs as the first statement in a module, function, class, or method definition.

### Why?

It is important because docstrings are not just a convention.

If you put them in the right place, you can see the function documentation with the [`help()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) (and maybe even other tools):

```
>>> @app.route("/")
... def hello() -> str:
...     """
...     summary
...     """
...     return "Hello World"
... 
>>> help(hello)
Help on function hello in module __main__:

hello() -> str
    summary
```

This happens because, if a string literal is the first thing in the function declaration, the interpreter will set it to the `__doc__` attribute of the function:

```
>>> hello.__doc__
'\n    summary\n    '
```

`help()` basically just displays, nicely formatted, the value of the `__doc__` attribute.

Comment: More precisely, the `def` statement uses a string in that position to set the `__doc__` attribute of the `function` (which is what tools like `help` look for).

Comment: @chepner good point! I tried to incorporate it into the answer. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 5):

Neither, they should go under the function header, like so:

```py
@app.route("/")
def hello() -> str:
    """
    summary
    """
    return "Hello World"
```

[PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) discusses the convention for docstrings in more detail. It states that these docstrings are set to the `__doc__` attribute of a given function or class (as described in the PEP linked above).

> A docstring is a string literal that occurs as the first statement in a module, function, class, or method definition. **Such a docstring becomes the __doc__ special attribute of that object.**

These docstrings appear when `help()` is invoked, like as follows:

```
>>> @app.route("/")
... def hello() -> str:
...     """
...     summary
...     """
...     return "Hello World"
...
>>> help(hello)
Help on function hello in module __main__:

hello() -> str
    summary
```

The other placements you've described do not set the `__doc__` attribute, and thus do not have the same behavior with `help()`.